# line 7: [: echo: integer expression expected

Tags: bash

This is my first script for Shell/Bash and I'm struggling with the syntax. The first command line argument is a string while the second is number.

```
x='echo $1|wc -m'
count=0
while
        [ $count -le $x ]                         #line 7
do
        count=$(( $count+1 ))
        echo $1
done
if
        [ $2 -lt 0 ]
then
        echo 'Negative'
else
        echo 'Positive'
fi
```

Comment: Hint: the problem is in `x='echo $1|wc -m'`

Comment: @devnull I found that part online, so I guess I shouldn't be surprised it doesn't work. Would this work better:              echo ${#$1}    (or at all)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this script? At least tell us how you call it (ie. with what parameters). It is good practice to put comments (`# ....`) in your scripts specifying those things/expected parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
x=$(echo "$1" | wc -m)
```

or:

```
x=`echo "$1" | wc -m`
```

You quoted the subcommand, so you didn't execute it.